# In SQL, how can I show the first row of a group and hide one column in the rest of the group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, resultset

I am trying to export an SQL query to Excel, and I need this behaviour but I can't find in anywhere.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

```
|c1|    c2     |
----------------
|a | sometext1 |
|a | sometext2 |
|a | sometext3 |
|a | sometext4 |
|b | sometext5 |
|b | sometext6 |
|b | sometext7 |
```

I want to show the results like this:

```
|c1|    c2     |
|a | sometext1 |
|  | sometext2 |
|  | sometext3 |
|  | sometext4 |
|b | sometext5 |
|  | sometext6 |
|  | sometext7 |
```

I want to show only the first item in each group, and hide the rest so it's not shown in Excel.
I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really do this type of processing in the application, not the database.  Why?  Because result sets represent *unordered* sets.  Relying on the ordering to understand data  makes the results brittle.

But you can.  One method is:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then c1 end) as c1, c2
from (select, t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by c1 order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by c1, seqnum;
```